# Why this Interface Instance give error when reference to an class Instance which implement that interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm new to java and when trying some `what is the output` question i found that.

This line `InterfaceB obj = new ClassA();` gives error while others are not.

I know that A super class variable can reference a sub class variable same goes of interface.
But what happens in that case. I want to know what is going on behind the seen.

```
interface InterfaceA { void methodA(); }

interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA { void methodB(); }

class ClassA implements InterfaceA
{
     public void methodA() {}
     public void methodB() {}
}

class ClassB extends ClassA implements InterfaceB
{
     public ClassB() {}
     // InterfaceA obj = new ClassA(); no error 
     InterfaceB obj = new ClassA(); //give  error: incompatible types
     // InterfaceA obj = new ClassB(); no error
     // InterfaceB obj = new ClassB(); no error
      // ClassA obj = new ClassB(); no error
}

public class Online4 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because ClassA does not implement Interface B.

Always remember that a parent type in java can refer to Subtype.

Type IntefaceB is no way related to type ClassA here. And for below to work

```
InterfaceB obj = new ClassA();
```

ClassA need to have its parent type to be InterfaceB(either directly or by anyother type which implements InterfaceB(a class) or extends InterfaceB(interface).

Comment: I missed that InterfaceA is the parent in Hierarchy and InteraceB and ClassA are like siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Interface references can hold the reference to the objects, implenting that interface. In your case your classA is not implementing the interfac B hence you are getting the error at:

```
InterfaceB obj = new ClassA();
```

In all other commented cases in your code. The reference of interface used is actually holding an object of a class(child/parent), which implements that interface.

Answer (score 1):

**An interface contains behaviors that a class implements.**

In your case `ClassA` does not implement Interface B.

```
 InterfaceB obj = new ClassA(); //give  error: incompatible types
```

to make that line work you can extend your interfaceA with **interfaceB**

```
interface InterfaceA  extends InterfaceB
```

Now

```
   InterfaceB obj = new ClassA(); //compiles
```

you are doing in reverse. where `InterfaceB` is parent of `InterfaceA`.

Answer (score 1):

To state the inheritance chain clearly:

1) InterfaceB is a child of Interface A

2) Class A is a child of Interface A

3) Class B is a child of Interface B and Class A(and hence Interface A)

Parent variable(Interface or Class) type can hold child(class) instance.
Anything outside of this is going to throw an error.